# jQuery can't slideToggle my seperate divs properly with individual buttons

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to have my hidden description div open and close upon the press of a button, however, I'm going to apply this to a bigger project where the divs will be dynamically generated (by Django), so I am avoiding using specific IDs and classes. However when I press one button, all my descriptions open rather than the one element I clicked on. Sorry if this is poorly worded but my codepen link shows you what I'm getting at.

HTML:

```
    <html>
<head>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
<body>

<div id="list">
  <div class="item">

    <div class="item-name">
    <p> This is an item name </p>
    </div>

    <div class="buttons">
      <div class="down-info">
        <button id="down-btn" class="btn dropdown-toggle">
          <i class="icon-chevron-down"></i>
        </button>
      </div>

      <div class="delete-item">
        <button class="btn dropdown-toggle">
          <i class="icon-trash"></i>
        </button>
      </div>

      <div class="check-item">
<button class="btn dropdown-toggle">
<i class="icon-ok"></i>
</button>
</div>
</div>
<div class="description">
<p>This is an item description, I'm wondering how much space I can occupy here before everthing looks too cluttered.</p>
</div>
</div>

    <div class="item">
      <div class="item-name">
        <p> This is an item name </p>
      </div>
      <div class="buttons">
        <div class="down-info">
          <button id="down-btn" class="btn dropdown-toggle">
            <i class="icon-chevron-down"></i>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="delete-item">
          <button class="btn dropdown-toggle">
            <i class="icon-trash"></i>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="check-item">
          <button class="btn dropdown-toggle">
            <i class="icon-ok"></i>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="description">
        <p>This is an item description, I'm wondering how much space I can occupy here before everthing looks too cluttered.</p>
      </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
html{
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
#list {
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.item {
  height: 40px;
  width: 410px;
  background-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: grey;
  margin-top: -1px;

  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
}

#list > .item:first-child {
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
}

#list > .item:last-child {
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}

  .item-name > p {
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 10px 0px 0px 15px;
    text-align: left;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  }

.check-item, .down-info, .delete-item {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: -41px;
}

.btn {   
    outline: none !important;
}

.down-info > button, .check-item > button, .delete-item > button {
  padding: 10px 11px 10px 11px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
}

  .down-info {
    margin-left: 410px;
  }

 .delete-item {
    margin-left: 447px;
  }

 .check-item {
    margin-left: 484px;
  }

.description {
  width: 382px;
  height: auto;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-left: 64px;

  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;

  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.03);
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.03);
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.03);
}

.description > p {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 10px 10px 5px 15px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(".down-info").click(function()    {
$(".description").slideToggle('slow');
});
```

http://codepen.io/nmbusman/pen/ZYogje

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because when you do `$(".description").slideToggle('slow');` you select all the ".description" elements and toggle them. What you need to do is to toggle only one ".description" element inside the clicked button parent ".item" element.

Edited your jQuery code a little:

```
$(".down-info").click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.item').find(".description").slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your jquery to this:

```
$(".down-info").click(function()    {
    $(this).parent().next(".description").slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I tried with .sibling and .next and couldn't get it to work, didn't think about .parent, thanks!